# Upload theme button don't work in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have installed Wordpress in my Godaddy hosting.Its working quite well except i cant upload a new theme. when i click Appearance > Themes and then `add new` nothing shows up. The only thing that shows up are the buttons `featured` , `most popular` etc but when i click them nothing happens. When i press the `upload theme` button nothing happens either. How do i fix this?
I have tried it switching the default theme, deactivating all plugin but nothing resolver the problem. Godaddy support says that i will get a conformatin mail after the installation process completed within 24hours. Its almost 24hours but i haven't got any conformation mail. What can i do?? Do i really need to wait for the conformation. i can visit my blog but cant upload any theme, whats going wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You can add your theme directly in your Wordpress installation. For this go to `public-html/wp-content/themes/` and drop your theme folder here. Remember that your theme files must not be in subfolders of the folder e.g. `/themes/your-theme/theme-files-and-folders/`

Comment: I also tried that. but i am using zerif lite theme which shows errorif i upload in that way.And after some research i found the founder of this theme recommended to upload using `wp-admin` . but i cant upload any theme from `wp-admin`.

Comment: Can your reproduce the error given? Is the error promts whenever you try to activate the theme? Can you also check the console for JavaScript error?

Comment: My error was `syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION) in /home/basharnozibulla/public_html/wp-content/themes/zerif-lite/inc/jetpack.php on line 1`

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem on my localhost installation. I added the theme the way I mentioned in my answer and no error occurs. Probably not the best solution, but getting new clear installation can solve the problem.

Comment: the theme contributor said its the FTP which may sometime occur the problem

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? Can you remove all other themes and check again? Shut down also all plugins. If you start developing your theme and content or customizations are made, can your perform a quick new installation. It won't take your longer than 10 mins.

Comment: From Where do i check my console error in firefox. i have firebug and check for console in error tab but nothing founf

Comment: I tried reinstalling wordpress but no help still the same error

Comment: I've just researched your problem in wordpress's support forum and saw your already raised the issue to the developer. Sorry we didn't find a working solution.

Comment: Yah i also saw that. So you mean the is not resolved yet??

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue today and solved it using these steps:

1. Download the Theme **.zip** file to your machine.
2. In **cPanel File Manager**, navigate to your **Themes folder**. Depending on your hosting, path to Themes folder can differ a bit but essentially you are looking for public_html inside which you’ll find /wp-content/themes/.
3. Once you’re inside the **Themes folder** in cPanel File Manager, click on Upload and upload that .zip file you saved in Step 1.
4. Once the .zip file is uploaded, right click on the name of that file in cPanel and select **Extract** from the context menu.
5. Now you can refresh the WordPress themes page and you should be able to **Activate** it.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was theme related. I just renamed my current theme and then the default theme was automatically activated. Then i was able to upload my zerif lite theme and its now working fine.

Answer (score -1):

I have been through this issue and i have solved it!

it happens mainly when yu transfer wordpress database from another location!

Solution:
UNinstall and deactivate all themes! delete and re install! if you cant delete the theme due to modifications, decativate the theme switch to another new theme by installing from wordpress and then reverting back to old theme!
if the problem persists: Reset server!